# creat a new column and add value to it in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, correlation

Here's my code:

```
correlation <- function(dtable){
  # create the column
  dtable[, "correlation"] <- ""
  for (row in 1:nrow(dtable)) {
    #get the correlation for each row
    cor = cor(dtable$wells_per_section[1:row], dtable$section_eur[1:row])
    #store the value to the correlation column
    correlation = cor
  }
}
```

When I tried with my table it's returning NA, nothing added to the column, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not assigning the result of the `cor()` function to the `correlation` columns, and it is not explicitly returning `dtable`. Perhaps you can rewrite it, with some changes, as below:

```
correlation <- function(dtable){
  # create the column
  dtable[, "correlation"] <- NA
  for (row in 1:nrow(dtable)) {
    #get the correlation for each row
    dtable[row,"correlation"] <- cor(dtable$wells_per_section[1:row], dtable$section_eur[1:row])
  }
  return(dtable)
}
```

If of interest, you can acheive the same like this:

```
dtable["correlation"] = sapply(1:nrow(dtable),\(i) cor(dtable[1:i,1], dtable[1:i,2]))
```

### Update

The OP now wants to do correlation separately by groups of 16 rows.

I think the way to approach this is to making a grouping variable using `sort(rep(..., length.out=..))` as below, and then apply a simple function by this group..

```
f <- function(w,s) {
  sapply(seq_along(w), \(i) cor(w[1:i],s[1:i]))
}

dtable %>% 
  group_by(grp = sort(rep(1:16, length.out=250))) %>% 
  mutate(correlation = f(wells_per_section,section_eur))
```

Comment: Thank you! Right now it'll be the correlation of the first row all the way to the last, I need to add one more step to restart this correlation every 16 rows, can I do a for loop inside a for loop?

Comment: so each set of 16 rows is a separate group?

Comment: Yes that's right, please let me know if you need to see the actual data. Thank you!

Comment: sure, see update

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly the way I want it! And one last question for this data series, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567936/conditional-if-statement-and-loop-over-in-r Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: f <- function(w,s) sapply(seq_along(w), \(i) cor(w[1:i],s[1:i]))
Can you please break down this function? Why you have a function() before sapply? Thanks!

Comment: The function takes a vector of wells_per_section, `w` and the vector of section_eur, `s` and does the same type of `sapply(), cor()` estimation that I did in the first answer, and returns the resulting vector. I've used a shortcut (i.e. without the { }, but I've updated the answer to show you what I mean

Comment: Regarding the other question that you linked to, I couldn't understand what you were asking. Its really important to try and show what your desired output looks like. I see someone has already provided an answer; if that is not sufficient try to show your expected output, as part of your question

Comment: That's not the output I'm looking for. I just updated the output, thank you!