# conditional if statement and loop over in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Here's the dataset (only a small portion of it):

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~num_per_section,        ~unit,     ~section,         ~incr,       ~growth_factor,      ~correlation,
              4,                 1L, 271367.963168022, 271367.963168022,  271367.963168022,                    1,                 1,
```

I need to get the breakeven point, first look for the 16th row of correlation for each id, if it's > 0.999, breakeven = 16,
if not, go to the growth_factor column, count the last value that's >0.8 before <0.8 (there're times that is 0.9, 0.88, 0.7, 0.9 but the breakeven would be 2) And it will be a new data frame since for each id since it will have fewer rows.

I'm thinking about an if statement with two conditions.
Here's the desired output:

```
output


id breakeven
 4         2
 5         4
 6         2
 7         4
 8         2
 9        16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(case_when(
    last(correlation) > 0.999 ~ row_number() == n(),
    T ~ (growth_factor > 0.8 & lead(growth_factor) < 0.8)
  )) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  select(id, num_per_section) %>%
  rename(breakeven = num_per_section)

     id breakeven
  <dbl>     <int>
1     4         2
2     5         4
3     6         2
4     7         4
5     8         2
6     9        16
```

Comment: Hello Park, I updated the output, this is not exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Solicia May I ask `breakeven` for `id9` is 16?

Comment: I updated the input so it better explains what I mean for the 16

Comment: @Solicia I didn't notice that your data has been changed. I update my code.